# Where to put selector of NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, menu

I try to understand a few things in Cocoa but I got stuck on one thing. I'm following [Minimalistic Cocoa Programming](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html), there it is a `NSMenuItem` responsible for terminating the app. Now, I would like to create another `NSMenuItem`, with a shortcut, that when pressed, it `NSLog`-s something. But I don't know where should I put the implementation of said selector? Should I subclass the whole `NSApplication`? Should I `setDelegate` to some `NSObject` instance, acting as a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class that can be used as the target of the menu item. Something like this:

```
@interface Tester : NSObject
@end
@implementation Tester
- (void)logTest:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
@end
```

Then set it as the target:

```
id testMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log Test" action:@selector(logTest:) keyEquivalent:@"l"] autorelease];
id tester = [[[Tester alloc] init] autorelease];
[testMenuItem setTarget:tester];
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The first block of code is a subclass of NSObject, called Tester, right? Totally independent of the app? Then, the second block of code is where? I assume it's in different file, possibly in `initWithFrame:` or `awakeFromNib` of AppDelegate? I mean, those are two different classes, how do I make `logTest:` visible in the second block of code? I tried to setDelegate it to Tester, and it works, I'm just not sure if it's the right way.

Comment: In another words, please look at the link above, where should I put the Tester class? Also, is it possible to create the selector without creating another class? I mean, in the code from the link above, there is no subclassing, where should I put the `logTest:`?

Comment: You can put it before main(). And yes, you need an object of some class to use as a target of the menu item. In Matt's code he is using an existing method in NSApplication, that is why he didn't need to create a new class. Maybe someday Apple will allow blocks to be used as the action, then you wouldn't need the other class.

Comment: Ok, so just to check if I understood correctly: I have two possibilities: a) I create another class (with `logTest:` handler) and then `setDelegate` it from main, this is what I need to do if I want to structure the code like Matt is doing; b) I create MyAppDelegate (which is basically NSObject), somehow call it from main, and as I create the whole appdelegate myself, I can write a custom method to handle `logTest:` - this is what XCode is doing. Am I understanding this correctly?