# Where to put MainMenu.xib selector?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have a new project I am working on in Xcode 5.1 and I have been using Interface Builder to create and bind most of my layouts. I customized the default `MainMenu.xib` to contain the menu items I want but I cannot figure out how to bind the selectors for each menu item.

The project has a `MainWindow.xib` and a `MainWindowController` that is used by my app delegate and the controller is where I would expect the menu selectors to go, but I don't know how to do that.

- The drag-and-drop connections panel will not work with the controller.
- The MainMenu.xib's owner is the NSApplication, which doesn't seem right for the selector.

How do (and where should) I handle the MainMenu.xib actions?

Note: my question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365127/where-to-put-selector-of-nsmenuitem) but since I have done everything in IB and the accepted answer is in obj-c, the answer is of no use to me.

Answer (score 1):

In my own project, I have a MainMenu.xib and a MainWindow.xib file.

MainMenu.xib is the default starting xib file when one isn't using a storyboard for an app.  That's why NSApplication lives in there, it needs to be instantiated.

My MainWindow.xib is owned by my own MainWindowController implementation.

For the various menu items in MainMenu.xib, I am pointing those items at my AppDelegate (which is the true file owner for MainMenu.xib), and with those IBActions I'm firing off methods in other objects, notifications to other objects, or instantiating objects to get whatever task done that's associated with that menu item.

If you have additional classes & objects instantiated within MainMenu.xib, you can add IBActions in those classes and connect the menu items directly to them.

Comment: That is working great. Just curious. I was under the impression that it is bad practice to put stuff into the app delegate. I thought it was supposed to be boilerplate. Is that not the case?

Comment: In general, I believe ***it is*** bad practice to load down your app delegate with methods and routines, but as you get more experience in iOS development, you'll probably instantiate more objects in your MainMenu.xib file (or storyboard) and connect your menus to IBActions located in classes & objects that aren't your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Offhand, do you know any good blogs or patterns that go into detail about how to properly structure that sort of thing?